# How to move gun projectile in state line

Tags: c++

I have spawn point of projectile and I have to move it in state line direction but I don't know the destination point. So what formula or concept I will have to write to go in state line of projectile.

Suppose spawn point is (4,5) so it should go towards the direction (-4,-5), for any coordinate value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question again? Appart from the formulas x = x_0 + t * v_x, y = y_0 + t * v_y what else could you expect as an answer to this question?

Comment: Glad you liked my answer, does it deserve also a +1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given some x you find y using the **two point formula**:

```
y = y1 + (x-x1)*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

except when x2==x1

Alternatively, for a given y you get x:

```
x = x1 + (y-y1)*(x2-x1)/(y2-y1)
```

except when y2==y1

So, you have

```
y= 5.0 + (x+4.0)*(8.0)/(10.0)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation